# Undstanding GDK Remote GPS Provider

Tags: android, gps, google-gdk, location-provider

Is the Remote GPS Provider in the GDK always on? I thought the remote gps provider is getting the location update from the phone, but I purposely turn off the GPS on my phone and It is still returning true when I check if the provider is enabled.

```
locationManager.isProviderEnabled("remote_gps")
```

So How I can check if the user has GPS enable on their phone?